# Remove the masking of input field and then get the length of the input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to replace the masked input field value in javascript and then get the length of the replaced value. This is the input field with the submit button:

```
    <input id="HomePhone" class="phone" placeholder="(___) ___-____"/>
    <input style="float: right; margin-bottom:20px" type="submit" id="myBtn1" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
```

Below is the masking on the input field:

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.3.4/jquery.inputmask.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("#HomePhone").inputmask({ "mask": "(999) 999-9999" });
        
    </script>
```

I want to get the length of the input field and then display an error message if the length of the field is less than 10. The issue is that the length of the input field is always 14 because of the masking. This is what I did to remove the masking:

```
var test = document.getElementById("HomePhone").innerHTML.replace(/\D/g, '');

<script>
    if(document.getElementById("HomePhone").value != "" && document.getElementById("test").value.length <10)
    {
      alert("Phone needs to be 10 digits long");
    }
    
    </script>
```

The above code does not work because when I am running this statement:

```
document.getElementById("test").value.length
```

the above statement is always blank. I just want to remove the masking and then get the length of the result.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: _When_ do you want to run this validation?

Comment: On submit of the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line: `var test = document.getElementById("HomePhone").innerHTML.replace(/\D/g, '');` assigns a *string* to the variable `test`, it does not create a DOM element. This is why  `document.getElementById("test")` is doing nothing for you - you do not have an element with `id="test"`.

In your `submit` event handler, you need to get the value of `#HomePhone`, perform the regex replace on it to get just the digits and then do the length comparison.

```js
$(function () {
  $("#HomePhone").inputmask({ "mask": "(999) 999-9999" });
  
  $('form').on('submit', function (event) {
    const homePhone = $('#HomePhone').val().replace(/\D/g, '');
    
    if (0 < homePhone.length && homePhone.length < 10) {
      alert("Phone needs to be 10 digits long");
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.3.4/jquery.inputmask.bundle.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input id="HomePhone" class="phone" placeholder="(___) ___-____"/>
  <input style="float: right; margin-bottom:20px" type="submit" id="myBtn1" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
</form>
```

Comment: 76484, In the above code, homePhone is not a required field. I tried to modify the code this way: homePhone.length < 10 && document.getElementById("HomePhoneInput").value != "", but it didnt work

Comment: @rimi That's fine, in that case just also check to see if the `homePhone.length > 0`. I have updated the code snippet.